# Require all cells to CONCATENATE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, concatenation

I'm looking to use the concatenate formula to run a multi VLOOKUP. All cells in the CONCATENATE are required to return back the correct information. When cells are blank the CONCATENATE returns only one or two of the cells, ultimately returning  incorrect information in the lookup.

How do I require CONCATENATE to only work if all the cells are populated? I'd rather it return an error than incorrect information.

Please help!

EDIT:

The formula I'm using is as follows: =CONCATENATE([@[EXPENDITURE ORGANIZATION]],[@[EXPENDITURE TYPE]],[@[ACCOUNT_DESC]])

The formula lists the table headers. For some rows, these cells are blank as mentioned

Comment: please mock up some data and expected output.  Also show what your formula is and what it is outputting that in correct.

Comment: Hi Scott, added the formula. Does this make sense? I'd very much appreciate your help

Comment: That is not enough.  we need to see some test data and expected output.

Comment: 1. your formula doesn't have a `VLOOKUP` in it. 2. the '@' notation means 'the value from that field that is in this row' 3. your formula as described will do exactly what you want - `CONCATENATE` doesn't care if a value is blank; it'll return whatever is in the cell referenced. so in your case if there is no value for [EXPENDITURE ORGANIZATION] in a given row, the `CONCATENATE` output on that row will simply display the values for [EXPENDITURE TYPE] and [ACCOUNT_DESC] for that record. So, you should be all set. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wrap it in an IF function:

`=IF(OR([@[EXPENDITURE ORGANIZATION]]="", [@[EXPENDITURE TYPE]]="", [@[ACCOUNT_DESC]]=""), "", CONCATENATE([@[EXPENDITURE ORGANIZATION]],[@[EXPENDITURE TYPE]],[@[ACCOUNT_DESC]]))`

Comment: Worked! Thank you!